# How do you access .properties files inside an AppEngine app?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I've got an AppEngine app with two different instances, one for prod and one for staging. Accordingly, I'd like to configure the staging instance slightly differently, since it'll be used for testing. Disabling emails, talking to a different test backend for data, that kind of thing.

My first intuition was to use a .properties file, but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm using Gradle as a build system, so the file is saved in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/staging.properties` (and a matching `production.properties` next to it). I'm trying to access it like so:

```
public class Config {
  private static Config sInstance = null;
  private Properties mProperties;

  public static Config getInstance() {
    if (sInstance == null) {
      sInstance = new Config();
    }
    return sInstance;
  }

  private Config() {
    // Select properties filename.
    String filename;
    if (!STAGING) {  // PRODUCTION SETTINGS
      filename = "/WEB-INF/production.properties";
    } else {  // DEBUG SETTINGS
      filename = "/WEB-INF/staging.properties";
    }

    // Get handle to file.
    InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
    if (stream == null) {
      // --> Crashes here. <--
      throw new ExceptionInInitializerError("Unable to open settings file: " + filename);
    }

    // Parse.
    mProperties = new Properties();
    try {
      mProperties.load(stream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
    }
  }
```

The problem is that `getResourceAsStream()` is always returning `null`. I checked the build/exploded-app directory, and the .properties file shows up there. I also checked the .war file, and found the .properties file there as well.

I've also tried moving the file into `/WEB-INF/classes`, but that didn't make a difference either.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
```

or

```
InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);
```